Why dot (&bull;) is not vertically aligned to middle?

I tried to it in many ways, but this the closest to what I'm trying to do. I've added "vertical-align" to both elements but still it has some pixels more at the top I guess...
What am I doing wrong? Is there some way to do it? I've tried with margins and paddings, but it doesn't work.
<span style="font-size: 35px; color: #cb141b; line-height: 1px; vertical-align: middle; margin-bottom: 7px;">&bull;</span><span style="vertical-align: middle; ">We... KMC ...</span>


To the middle of what? I think you've forgottent hat some characters have desenders (g for example) - it just so happens that your text doesn't have any such characters, but what if it did?

Trying to clarify what you want - do you want it to be visually vertically centered on the W?

As you've correctly identified, you need:
vertical-align: middle;

It's sufficient to apply that to the bullet.
N.B. As a phrasing element with a default display of inline, the element <span> usually appears within a block-level text element with a default display of block such as <h2> or <p>.

Working Example:


.paragraph {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.bullet {
  color: #cb141b;
  font-size: 35px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
<p class="paragraph">
  <span class="bullet">&bull;</span>
  <span class="text">We... KMC ...</span>
</p>



